# retrieve image to picture box from database in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

How to retrieve image to PictureBox in c# winforms? I tried this codes but I am having an argument exception saying that the parameter is not valid in my bitmap.

```
con = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
                  "select companyLogo from companyDetailsTbl where companyId = 1", con);
        byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
        stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
        con.Close();
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream); //This is the error
        return bitmap;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A better way to do this:**

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnection))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select companyLogo from companyDetailsTbl where companyId = 1", con))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            pictureBox1.Image = ByteArrayToImage((byte[])(reader.GetValue(0)));
        }
    } 
}

public static Image ByteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn))
    { 
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(Bitmap));
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)tc.ConvertFrom(image);
```

Or:

```
byte[] image = (byte[])command.ExecuteScalar();
ImageConverter ic = new ImageConverter();
Image img = (Image)ic.ConvertFrom(image);
Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(img);
```